# Radio button white background, flash object and iFame on Chrome 21

Tags: html, css, flash, google-chrome, iframe

The problem occurs when we mix Flash objects and UI elements, like radio buttons, and we embed them in iframe. Problem reported on Chrome 21/Windows. Works correctly on Chrome 20.

Demo links:

- on iFrame: http://jsbin.com/agaxur/1/edit
- without iFrame: http://jsbin.com/agaxur/1/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I also have the exact issue. But I don't have any ideas to solve it.

However, I used a `jQuery plugin` called [prettyCheckboxes](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/)  as a workaround, and used a transparent radio button image from  [Niceforms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/niceforms.html).